# Goddess Voice Mix

Tags: voice, mix, suggestion

I have a task of mixing a female voice to make it sound "Goddess"-like and "Angel"-like and warm and soft and high-endy.

Those are pretty much the producer's words.

Any tips or hints or any past experiences you guys have? EQ, compression, reverb, effects?

I was going to make it very bright and airy and soft. Add a large maybe church reverb.

However, I don't know if a chorus effect or flange effect is proper for this type of thing.

It is narration - not dialogue of a character on screen, so at least I have a lot of lee-way to work with if I want.

I also can't think of any good examples of something like this I can reference to.

Comment: Hence the topic about not making a deadline, it all makes sense now :)

Comment: Tell me about it... Never done an angel voice before - didn't know where to start. Birdhouse saved my ___

Comment: Wow, that last comment brought back a weird memory from a while back. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOUzDGwX4kA

Comment: umm…I don't have the words to describe what I have just seen…

Comment: ROFLMAO! All I have to say after that is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rH9giCg3Nro.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

1. Duplicate the original read twice.
2. Roll-off most of the high end and boost some lows on one file, in an effort to make it "warm".
3. Roll-off everything below 6-8kHz on the other file in an effort to make it sound
   "whispery".
4. Layer these two elements.
5. Duplicate the "whispery" read and
   process it through a multi-tap delay.
6. Process the delayed "whispery" read
   through a soft, wide reverb like an infinite or cathedral, making
   the signal 100% wet.
7. Layer this new element with the 1st
   two.

See how far you get with that. Personally I would avoid flanging and phasing, but a very light chorus on one of the elements might sound nifty.

PS> For an extra-coolness boost, you could try a reverse reverb technique on the whispery read so that the words "suck in" on themselves, a la Poltergeist. Use with care, though, as it could sound scary or menacing.

Comment: @birdhousesound Thank you. You're an angel. Hah! I'm going to do this immediately. Thank you so much for the rapid reply!!! Will make my time here shorter.

Comment: Good luck and happy experimenting! I hope that my advice leads you to some cool, creative places. Above all, make sure you retain the clarity of the dialog.

Comment: @birdhousesound Hey I hope you're still up. Can't seem to get a good delay happening the way I want I think it should be. Any tips on parameters? I've tried all up and down about 100 milliseconds to about 1 second...

Comment: Yup, you caught me just in time. I would try Waves Super-tap (http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=273), preset "analog delay". Also look at the presets in Waves H-Delay (http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=9112).

Comment: @birdhousesound So I finished at 7:30AM this morning. Thanks for the help. It worked out great - did pretty much everything you suggested. The executive producers loved the voice and are now playing it around like mad. Success!!!

Comment: That's excellent! Would love to hear what you finally ended up with. Sleep well -

Comment: Wow.. Congrats, Ryan. I'm going to try that on some of my vocals. Thanks for the great question and answer guys!
